# Как происходит сочетание отрисовки OpenGL из под DirectX в Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, directx, render

Насколько мне известно, вывод графики в Windows старше XP, происходит с помощью технологии DirectX. А как происходит если в этом деле участвует OpenGL вывод?

Иллюстрация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я могу предположить два варианта:

1. Есть самостоятельная область для вывода из OpenGL приложения, которая образуется за счет работы OpenGL, а остальная область, тоже самостоятельная, отрисовывается с помощью DirectX.
2. Область вывода OpenGL передается в DirectX и потом все отрисовывается с помощью DirectX.

Подскажите, как все происходит на самом деле?

Comment: Дизассемблируйте библиотеку opengl - если она подключает direct библиотеки - то мостик будет просматриваться.

Comment: @nick_n_a как можно дизассемблировать `opengl` если это не библиотека - весь `opengl API` поставляется вместе с драйверами видеокарты

Comment: @ampawd , драйвера это те же dll файлы и они относятся к бинарным файлам. ну и из этого следует что их можно дизасемблировать. просто это как бы не готовый ответ. вопрос призывал дать готовый ответ знающего человека...

Comment: @Kromster поправил

Comment: Думаю всё зависит от производителя драйвера видеокарты. Реализация может быть разной для разных производителей. В любом случае, т.к. они используют одну и ту же видеокарту, то на уровне видеокарты DirectX или OpenGL может уже не иметь значение.

Answer (score 2):

Вот как называется и описывается компоновка "окон" в Windows - [Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager)

Вот тут описывается, как OpenGL себя ведет - [Windows Vista and OpenGL-the Facts](https://www.opengl.org/pipeline/article/vol003_9/)

Comment: то есть получается что directx и opengl имеют одинаковый приоритет. а их обработку на себя берет менеджер рабочего стола и отправляет то что сделал в видеодрайвер.

Comment: Звучит логично. Попробуйте поискать по ключевым словам из статей более свежие источники, но думаю, что все примерно так же и есть (и с Metal и Vulkan в том числе).

Answer (score -2):

Мне рассказывали что в "Windows старше XP" тупо нету отдельно OpenGL - оно просто "эмулируется" через DirectX. Но не проверял. Ибо не умею.

Comment: Ерунду вам, простите, рассказывали.